# Bootstrap dropdown in navbar not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a website in HTML and CSS. I have installed bootstrap and added in a navbar. The problem is that the navbar has two dropdown menus, neither of which are working. They show up in the navbar, but clicking on them does nothing.

Here is the code header information:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="my_portfolio.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin:500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Here is the code for the navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#skills">Skills<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Projects<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#schools">Schools</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Contact Me<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

And here is the Bootstrap JS info I added to the bottom of the body:

```
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Bootstrap Navbar element to work, you will also need the Bootstrap css file - get it here:
http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

or just insert this into your header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Make sure you have jQuery in your header too:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
```

Working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jsheridan390/3fuhLayt/

Comment: That did it. I added the jquery header and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Please mark this answer as correct, if it fixed your problem.

Answer (score -1):

just change href="#" to href=""

```
 <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Contact Me<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
```

Working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/15547/

Answer (score -1):

Be careful u are including bootstrap js below the jquery and also check console is there any error ?

Answer (score -1):

Do you have include jquery into head ?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```